# bottomSheetDialogFragment.setCancelable(false) is not working? I want to prevent from dismiss of bottom sheet dialog from out side touch on screen?

Tags: dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

I want to perform some tasks when user touch outside the bottom sheet fragment. How can I do this?

In my bottom sheet dialog there's a piece of code to prevent from closing when touch outside....

```
bottomSheetDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: Please edit your title to make it shorter and use code style for your code.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried just now and it is working.

```
 BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
 bottomSheetFragment.setCancelable(false);
 bottomSheetFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), 
                                                bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
```